# New help converting XML Data Set, Datarid to HTML output using C#, .NEt 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, html, datagrid

In a new class I'm writing, I need to take the contents of an external XML data feed and convert it into an HTML table via C# and .NET 2.0 (cannot go any higher due to server constraints). Since we reuse the code, I'm putting this functionality into a class. Here is the XML Loader class:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace 
{
    public partial class XMLLoader
    {
        private String xmlpath = "\\xml\\data_test.xml";

    public String getXMLData()
    {
        DataSet dsXMLData = new DataSet("xml_data");
        string filePath = xmlpath;
        dsXMLData.ReadXml(filePath);
        Debug.WriteLine(dsXMLData.GetXml());

        DataGrid DataGrid1 = new DataGrid();
        DataGrid1.AllowPaging = true;
        DataGrid1.DataSource = dsXMLData;
        DataGrid1.DataMember = "xml_data";

        StringBuilder outStr = new  StringBuilder(String.Empty);
        outStr.Append(dsXMLData.GetXml());
        return outStr.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Where I am getting stuck is outputting the contents of the data grid to an HTML Table using the outStr var which I am simply writing to the APSX page using <% Response.Write(); %>. Either way I'm stuck and so far not finding what I want to display in MSDN.

Comment: OK, I am going to use <asp:datagrid> to draw the results to the page and a simply code behind to load the XML. Works good. But now for some reason, when I custom bind the columns to a XML node, the records get stuck and don't iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the method `Databind()` to your datagrid and add your datagrid to your page controls.

EDIT:

You can also use the method `Render(yourHTMLTextWriter)` of your datagrid after the binding

Comment: Gregoire, thanks.
If I have <% Response.Write(getHTMLTable()); %> in my APSX page and 
protected String getHTMLTable()
        {
            XMLLoader xl = new XMLLoader ();
            return xl.loadXML();
        }
 in my .cs page, how would I get the HTML to the APSX page via HTMLTextWriter?

Comment: @JFOX: try yourGrid.Render(Response.Output)

Comment: Thanks Gregoire, see new comment above.